# How to nest properties in Class Variance Authority?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to do the following in CVA?

```
const mathPanelVariants = cva(
  'relative mt-[100px] w-full rounded-sm border-l-[3px] px-[24px] py-[16px]',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        theorem: { box: 'border-l-[#617bff] dark:bg-[#182635] bg-[#e0ecff]' },
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'theorem',
    },
  }
);
```

SO that property `box` is nested inside `theorem`? User should call `<MathPanel variant="theorem"/>` and then I should be able to access `box` classes and potentially others separately like this: `mathPanelVariants({ variant: "theorem" }).box`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible. This is because the usage of `cva()` is to have the variants be applied onto the string of classes given in the first argument of the `cva()` function call.

Instead, you could have separate `cva()`-constructed functions for the different sets of classes:

```html
<script type="module">
import { cva } from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/class-variance-authority@0.7.0';

const boxVariants = cva(
 '',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        theorem: 'border-l-[#617bff] dark:bg-[#182635] bg-[#e0ecff]',
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'theorem',
    },
  }
);
console.log(boxVariants({ variant: 'theorem' }));

const fooVariants = cva(
 '',
  {
    variants: {
      variant: {
        theorem: 'foo'
      },
    },
    defaultVariants: {
      variant: 'theorem',
    },
  }
);
console.log(fooVariants({ variant: 'theorem' }));
</script>
```

You could refactor these calls into a separate function that looks like your original API. This API could use `cva()` under the hood.